# Trying to delete a Radio Button in a Bluebeam Stamp with Java

Tags: javascript

[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPIBA.png) I work at an Arch firm. We are trying to build a smart stamp in Bluebeam Revu- we started with a Revu Template. We would like to remove the radio buttons in the stamp, but when we do, the stamp is no longer dynamic.

```
var builder = 
{
 // These map to Text Fields in the Stamp
 textBoxes :
 [
  { field:"CheckedBy", description:"Checked by:", default:function() { return Collab.user; } },  
  { field:"Date", description:"Date:", default:function() 
   {  
    var curDate = new Date();
    return (curDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + curDate.getDate() + "/" + curDate.getFullYear();
   } 
  }
 ],
 // This maps to a Radio Group in the PDF named 'Type of Submittal'
 radioGroup : "Document Type", 
 radioButtons :
 [
  // value maps to the 'Choice' of each radio button in the group, description will show on the dialog
  { value:"SubmittalForApproval", description:"Submittal For Approval"}, 
  { value:"Resubmittal", description:"Re-Submittal For Approval" }
 ],
 checkBoxes : 
 [
  { field:"REVIEWED" }, 
  { field:"EXCEPTIONS AS NOTED" }, 
  { field:"REVISE AND RESUBMIT" }, 
  { field:"REJECTED" }, 
  { field:"SUBMIT ITEMS NOTED" }, 
  { field:"RECEIVED FOR INFO ONLY" }, 
  { field:"SEE REVIEW SHEET" }, 
  { field:"SEE CONSULTANT REVIEW" }
 ]
}
```

When we delete the section that builds the radio button, the dynamic stamp UI no longer works